# Match scrolling UVs for quads of varying length

Tags: c++, opengl-es

I have a couple (3-4) bands (essentially long triangle strips) that share the same texture and basically start from the same location. I scroll that texture vertically by adding an offset every frame to the V coordinate. That offset is just a member variable that I add on to every frame (yes, it does get huge).

My problem is that the UVs originate from the end of the bands and update simultaneously, which means that the texture is synched up until the bands become different lengths. Their length is based on a simulation, so it can change every frame.

[image: Current vs Ideal]

How do I ensure that the calculation compensates for the difference in length every frame that I scroll the UVs? I'm having trouble with the math.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use the longest band as the basis from which to determine the UVs for everything else. If the longest band was from 0 to 1 (along it's length), then calculating the UVs for the shorter bands was as simple as using the percentage difference between the two bands.

i.e. A shorter band's V coordinate would go from 0 to shorterbandlength/longestbandlength.